# Circular dependency between the following tasks: :app:processDebugResources \--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

Tags: kotlin

> I have develop with Gradle (Android Studio), and i give the next error:
> I dont undestart why dont run, and i dont understand this error
> Code build.gradle

```
`plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.tareapmydm02'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tareapmydm02"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation project(path: ':app')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}`
```

**What is the problem?? I try compile and run but appear this error. I try all, but i dont get the compile and run**

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
\--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
\--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

I dont understand why not run